# CSS Var in darken function - using SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

To summarise what I'm trying to do; effectively, through the mix of CSS variables and SCSS variables I'm attempting to create a "dark mode" (while future proofing for other potential themes in future).

To start off with I created this SCSS map:

```
$themes: ( 
    default:( //Goes in :root
        Franklin-Blue: #1d1c4d, 
        Light-Blue: #4e5d94, 
        Pale-Blue: #7289da, 
        Pure-White: #ffffff, 
        VLight-Grey: #99aab5, 
        Middle-Grey: #2c2f33, 
        Dark-Grey: #23272a, 
        body-color: #ffffff, 
        text-color: #000000, 
        bold-text: #000000, 
        White-Blue: #ffffff 
     ), 
    dark: ( //page class tag
        Franklin-Blue: #000000,
        Light-Blue: #0d0d0d, 
        Pale-Blue: #2c2f33, 
        Pure-White: #ffffff, 
        VLight-Grey: #99aab5, 
        Middle-Grey: #2c2f33, 
        Dark-Grey: #23272a, 
        body-color: #000000, 
        text-color: #ffffff, 
        bold-text: #7289da, 
        White-Blue: #7289da 
    ) 
);
```

Then there's this mixin to setup the relevant CSS variables from it:

```
@mixin theme() {
    @each $theme, $map in $themes { //Cycle through the themes
        @if $theme == "default" { //default theme goes in root
            :root {
                @each $key, $value in $map {
                    #{--#{$key}}: $value;
                }
            }
        }
        @else {
            .#{$theme} {
                @each $key, $value in $map {
                    #{--#{$key}}: $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@include theme();
```

I then reference them using SCSS variables like so:

```
$Franklin-Blue-CSS-Var: var(--Franklin-Blue);
$Light-Blue-CSS-Var: var(--Light-Blue);
$Pale-Blue-CSS-Var: var(--Pale-Blue);
$White-CSS-Var: var(--Pure-White);
$White-Blue-CSS-Var: var(--White-Blue);
$Light-Grey-CSS-Var: var(--VLight-Grey);
$Middle-Grey-CSS-Var: var(--Middle-Grey);
$Dark-Grey-CSS-Var: var(--Dark-Grey);
```

Which works perfectly throughout most of the site; my issue is that one of the UI libraries we use doesn't seem to play ball when I pass those variables in. If I pass this arbitrary set of variables:

```
$white: $White-CSS-Var;
$gray-100: #d4d5d6;
$gray-200: #bfc0c1;
$gray-300: #aaabad;
$gray-400: #959799;
$gray-500: #808284;
$gray-600: #6b6d70;
$gray-700: #56585b;
$gray-800: #414347;
$gray-900: #2c2f33;
$black: #000000;
$blue: $Franklin-Blue-CSS-Var;
$indigo: #6610f2;
$purple: #6f42c1;
$pink: #e62276;
$red: #e93b3c;
$orange: #fd7e14;
$yellow: #f5ba38;
$green: #40ae49;
$teal: #20bec6;
$cyan: $teal;
$primary: $Light-Blue-CSS-Var;
$primary-font: $White-Blue-CSS-Var;
$secondary: $Light-Grey-CSS-Var;
$secondary-font: $White-Blue-CSS-Var;
$content-bg: $White-Blue-CSS-Var;
$content-popup-bg: $White-Blue-CSS-Var;
$success: $Franklin-Blue-CSS-Var;
$info: $teal;
$warning: $yellow;
$danger: $red;
$light: #f8f9fa;
$dark: $Dark-Grey-CSS-Var;
$page-bg: #f5f5f5;
$page-font: #333333;
```

When compiling down to CSS, I'm met with this error:

> Error: $color: var(--Light-Blue) is not a color. At line 2936: $acrdn-exp-hdr-hover-color: darken($primary, 15) !default;

Is there an easy way around this?

I suppose I could just maintain a couple of different SCSS variable sets (one for each mode) and load the relevant SCSS sheet dependant on color schemes. But, considering it's a 100,000+ line SCSS file as is, I don't really want to force the user to wait for the other file to come through just because they switched colour schemes.

Comment: No there isn't, since this is not how CSS custom properties work. You can remove the `darken()` function from the SCSS or pass a fix hex-value to the function.

Comment: Welp, looks like users are gonna be getting multiple versions of the same SCSS files then. I'll see if I can break that massive SCSS library down into components to save some of that load